# Round up date field to next half hour in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

In SQL, I have a `DATE` variable which I want to round to the next available half hour (i.e. xx:30). Note that this shouldn't just be to the *nearest* half hour.

Here are some examples:

```
Time                   Expected outcome
2012-03-26 11:25 AM    2012-03-26 11:30 AM
2012-03-26 11:45 AM    2012-03-26 12:30 PM
```

Is there a way to do this in SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gave a +1 to Justin's answer for the originality.

If you want a more pedantic (or, perhaps more easily understood or maintained) aproach,

```
select case when to_number(to_char(sysdate,'mi')) > 30
       then trunc(sysdate,'mi') + ((60 - to_number(to_char(sysdate,'mi')) +30)/1440)
       else trunc(sysdate,'mi') + (30 - to_number(to_char(sysdate,'mi')))/1440 end
from dual
```

I'm only tossing this in there as this might be a more adaptable approach if you needed to do something similar against other numbers, like 45 minutes past the hour for example. You would just replace the three 30s with 45s and away you go.

For performance, though, for your exact problem - Justin's is a real winner.

Answer (score 13):

It's a bit convoluted, but something like

```
SELECT round( (date_col - trunc(date_col)) * 48 )/ 48 +
         trunc( date_col )
  FROM dual
```

should work.

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  select round((sysdate - trunc(sysdate)) * 48)/48 + trunc(sysdate),
  2         sysdate
  3*   from dual
SQL> /

ROUND((SYSDATE-TRUNC SYSDATE
-------------------- --------------------
26-mar-2012 14:30:00 26-mar-2012 14:35:30
```

- `TRUNC(date_col)` truncates the time to midnight.
- `date_col - trunc(date_col)` returns the fraction of a day that has elapsed since midnight.
- Multiplying by 48 gives you the number of half-hour increments
- Rounding that gives you the nearest half-hour
- Then dividing by 48 gives you a fraction of a day that can be added back to the `trunc(date_col)`

Comment: This helps, but is not quite what I'm after.  This is rounding to the _nearest_ half-hour, but I need the _next_ half-hour that ends in :30.  So, in your example above with `14:35:30`, the expected result would be `15:30:00`.

Comment: And +1 for the clever solution.

Comment: This should definitely be the accepted answer ! To answer Paul who asked the NEXT, use ceil instead of round. For those who are interested by the PREVIOUS, user floor instead of round. Edit : This is explained in the next answers that I did not read at first, sorry

Answer (score 4):

Here's a little adjustment to Justin's answer that I think gives the results you want:

```
WITH thedate AS (SELECT trunc(SYSDATE)+6.5/48 thedate FROM dual)
select round((thedate - trunc(thedate)) * 24 - 1/(24*3600))/24 + trunc(thedate)+1/48,
          theDATE
     from thedate;
```

Basically, this rounds to the nearest hour (after subtracting a second to prevent rounding up when you are exactly on the half-hour) then adds a half hour.

Answer (score 3):

To get the next half hour, modify Justin Cave's solution by changing the ROUND to CEIL:

```
SELECT CEIL( (date_col - trunc(date_col)) * 48 )/ 48 +
         trunc( date_col )
  FROM dual
```

**ROUND** goes to the *nearest* (up or down), **CEIL** goes up to the *next* (always up).  **FLOOR** would go to the *previous* (always down).

To answer Michael Broughton's point about maintability:

48 is the number of "half hours" in a day.  To change the period, replace both instances with:

```
60/x * 24
```

where `x` is the number of minutes in the period you want.

E.g. Every 10 mins = (60/10) * 24 = 144.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

My code does this using ROUND function to round to the nearest hour and then adding half an hour

```
WITH thedate AS
     (SELECT TO_DATE ('2012-03-26 11:20 AM', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI AM') mydate
        FROM DUAL)
SELECT mydate,
       TO_CHAR (ROUND (mydate, 'HH') + 1 / 48,
                'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI AM'
               ) "Rounded Date"
  FROM thedate;
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

simplified (I hope)...

```
select 
  case
    when to_number(to_char(sysdate,'mi')) <= 30
      then trunc(sysdate,'hh24') + 30/1440
      else trunc(sysdate,'hh24') + 1/24
  end
from dual;
```